# Macros to copy content in Google docs and paste to new Google docs

Tags: documentation, google-docs

how can I use macros to copy the content of one Google Doc to a new doc?

Context : we currently write meeting minutes weekly; then we duplicate this doc to write for the next week.

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you need that functionality within Google Docs, and not Google Sheets, right? If so, you will need to use Apps Script. In the case that you refer to Sheets, you can also modify the macro using Google Scripts to do what you need. If you need more help, ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a long running version of the minutes doc instead of copying.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33581100)